# My Minecraft looks pixelated

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]I don't know but my cobblestone texture looks very pixelated when I'm coming nearer to them. And also, the outline of every block in the world looks very pixelated. When I watch the world from a distance, the views is not as I thought. It's very different than the Minecraft videos that I've watched from YouTube and images from other websites. I've also checked my graphic driver and it's already up to date.

Comment: You'll really need to add screen caps of what you're trying to describe, because 'pixelated' is exactly what Minecraft is.

Comment: Hey! Water's wet! What do I have to do?

Comment: Here's Minecraft Wiki's picture on how a Cobblestone stair is supposed to look like: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/File:Cobblestone_Stairs.png

Comment: "Pixelated" is what *everything* in Minecraft looks like. Have you played the game much?

Comment: I'm surprised you managed to buy Minecraft without knowing about this. I mean, just looking at [Mojang's site](https://mojang.com/) you can see plenty of screenshots with pixelated textures.

Comment: I've been having the same problem! WOW!

Comment: It's like when i watch my world in long distance, for example a tree. The leaves doesn't seems to be square at all. I don't know how to express it but it looks pixelated as I said 

Comment: @Raptor Are you sure it isn't just because you look at the from further away? Even pixelated textures look nice when you look at them from further away.

Answer (score 17):

Hate to break it to you but this is what vanilla (unmodified, standard) minecraft looks like. If you wanted any of the fancy crisp HD textures you have to download them separately.

Theyre in what are known as "Resources packs".

Go to a website like say, planetminecraft and download one, follow the instructions and you may run with a custom texture set. If your pc can handle, i recommend a HD pack.

Answer (score 9):

Yep, that's exactly what vanilla (without mods) Minecraft looks like.

There are a bunch of resource packs and other mods to change the look and that's probably what you've seen in those videos you mentioned.

I recommend taking to Google to find the texture packs I've mentioned. Unfortunately mod recommendations are off-topic for our site.

Comment: Texture Packs are outdated

Comment: @alex2003super So am I, when it comes to Minecraft :P

Comment: Don't worry. They've been named so for long (up to 1.5.2 :D)  and most of the people call them still so. RP basically have got not just textures replacements but also sound, music, languages, texts, splashes and models. You don't even need to change all the resources in a resource pack, you could just change a texture or change the whole resources!

Comment: @DJPirtu Same here, but its the same idea. Resource packs allow for more than just textures though - but i couldnt really tell you what off the topf my head

Answer (score -2):

Two ideas here.

**1.** Minecraft is supposed to be pixelated, it is how it's designed.

**2.** There may be something wrong with either Java or your GPU. Maybe even something running in the background responsible for rendering, so maybe even your CPU. There's many things that could cause it, but I'm not exactly sure.

This is the best answer I can give.